# How to trigger VS post-build events without rebuilding

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, rebuild, post-build-event

I have a bunch of VS 2005 C++ projects, which build a number of dlls and executables, which are a small part of a large interdependent file hierarchy. In order to debug the files, I copy the built execs/dlls to the hierarchy by post-build events.
Sometimes I update my hierarchy, but have all my projects up to date - in this case all I need to do is to execute post-build events (i.e. copy files) without rebuilding all the sources. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you do not rebuild, the build operation should not do more than execute those events, assuming there are no source code changes.

Comment: If there are no changes, and no build happened, post-build events won't be executed either